# How to append text to a specific lines in a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a text file (file.txt) having content something like:

```
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 
foo3 4562
```

It contains the process and respective PID.

Using shell script, I want to append a string (running/not running) to that lines in this file, according to the PID.

For example, in the above file, for line containing PID 3696, I want to append a string "running" at the end, so that the file becomes:

```
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 running
foo3 4562
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ sed '/3696/ s/$/running/' file.txt 
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 running
foo3 4562
```

or

```
$ sed 's/3696/& running/' file.txt 
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 running 
foo3 4562
```

Add the `-i` option to save the changes back to `file.txt`.

Comment: what will be the command if i want to append the text at a particular line? suppose at 3rd line..

Comment: @smya.dsh `sed '3s/$/ running/' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop to iterate over the lines in the file and run `ps` to check if the process if running:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    pid="$(awk '{print $NF}' <<< $line)"
    unset status
    if ps --no-headers -p "$pid" > /dev/null
    then
        status="running"
    fi
    echo "$line $status"
done < file
```

Comment: The awk split is somewhat unattractive, though. If the lines have a regular format, just do `while read name pid; do ... done <file`

Comment: The use of `awk` is terrible! please follow tripleee's advice!

Comment: I agree, but the reason I didn't use `read name pid` is because it is likely that a process could have multiple words e.g. `foo bar`. I didn't want to assume that the process would always be called a single word like `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$2==3696{$3="running";}1' your_file


>cat temp
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 
foo3 4562 
> awk '$2==3696{$3="running";}1' temp
foo1 3464 
foo2 3696 running
foo3 4562 
>
```

Comment: thank you.. it works fine.. but which command would be better to use?
i mean which command serves better performance?